# React setState hook updating one previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have react js and asp.net core application, onform submit i am trying to fill some master data and detail data(with in aray).
The problem is that, **setState** updates one previous value and my backend asp.net web api method gets hit when i press submit button twice. anyone can please tell me what is the proper way to update state so that i could submit correct data on first hit. I am calling another function **addDetailItem** from handleSubmit function to fill array using setState hook.

```
<form autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit = {handleSubmit}  >

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if(validateForm()){
        addDetailItem(); 
        props.createPaymentVoucher(values);
    }               
    console.log(values);                
}

const addDetailItem = () => {            
    let x = {
        voucherMasterId:values.voucherMasterId,
        voucherDetailId:0,                
        accountCode: values.creditAccountCode,
        debit: 0,
        credit: values.creditAmount,
        remarks: values.fromRemarks,
        status: ""
    }
    setValues({
        ...values,
        voucherDetails: [...values.voucherDetails, x]                
    });
    console.log('voucherDetails: ', values.voucherDetails);
}
```

here setValues setting the values but on first click it shows empty array and on second click it shows values which had to filled first time.

Comment: This seems to be missing information needed to answer this question.  What does *setValues* do?  How are your values displayed on the template?

Comment: setState is async function so when you try to use state immediately after updating it, it will always return previous value.

Comment: you may not get latest state value on the next line after  calling `setState`. You can use `useEffect` to listen to the state change and then update your UI according that.

Comment: @DanielGimenez setValues is useState function and iam setting values by it, like we initialize const [values,setValues]=useState({});

Comment: @SifatHaque here iam calling backend function and sending data to api from this handleSubmit function , i actually don't want change the UI i just want to send data from my function to backend, that's why i am not using useEffect here.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

**Just capture values changes using `useEffect`**

> - I passed the `values` as dependency in useEffect.
> - So, You will get the latest updated value of `values`
> - Now everytime anything changes in `values`, it will call `props.createPaymentVoucher`

```
useEffect(() => {
   props.createPaymentVoucher(values);
}, [values])

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();        
    if(validateForm()){
        addDetailItem(); 
    }                            
}

const addDetailItem = () => {            
    let x = {
        voucherMasterId:values.voucherMasterId,
        voucherDetailId:0,                
        accountCode: values.creditAccountCode,
        debit: 0,
        credit: values.creditAmount,
        remarks: values.fromRemarks,
        status: ""
    }
    setValues({
        ...values,
        voucherDetails: [...values.voucherDetails, x]                
    });
}
```

Comment: this is not suitable , as my values are also gettting set on every textbox onchange.

Answer (score 0):

setState is async function so when you try to use state immediately after updating it, it will always return previous value.

So instead of using state value immediately, you can use `useEffect` or either follow below solution for your specific use case.

Try:-

```
const newValues = { ...values, voucherDetails: [...values.voucherDetails, x]};
setValues({ ...newValues });
return newValues;
```

Now you can access your values in your `handleSubmit` function like below

```
const updatedValues = addDetailItem();
```